# Calc 1, limit error

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Apparently the following equals 2, what I'm getting though is 0.

Where is the mistake?

Find: $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2}{1 - cosx} $

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x*x}{1 - cosx} $ (expand numerator)

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} x*\frac{x}{1 - cosx} $ (move x outside numerator)

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} x $ * $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{1 - cosx} $ (product property of limits)

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} x $ * $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1 - cosx}{x}\right)^{-1} $ (inverse the fraction of the second limit)

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} x = 0 $ , and we know also that $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1 - cosx}{x}\right)=0 $

Therefore:

$ 0 * 0^{-1} $

$=0$

Comment: How is $0\cdot0^{-1}=0$? More concretely: The "product property of limits" you use is only valid if the limit of both factors exists. You correctly calculated $\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{1-\cos x}$ to be "$\frac10$", i.e. the limit does not exist.

Comment: Seriously? $0*0^{-1}=0$?

Comment: Use $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1$ instead.  Can you find a way to manipulate your expression to make use of that?

Comment: $$0 \times 0^{-1} = 0 \times \frac{1}{0}$$ which is undefined

Answer (score 2):

First of all, dividing by zero is a tricky business; statements like $0 \cdot 0^{-1} = 0$ make a mathematician shiver.

So the first step would be acknowledging that we are dealing with an indeterminacy; therefore, we should try to get rid of it.

Applying L'Hôpital's rule twice we get:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1 - \cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{\cos x} = 2
$$

Without L'Hôpital's rule, and remembering that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sin x}{x} = 1$, we can do something like:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1 - \cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{2 \sin^2 (\frac{x}{2})} = \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \cdot \frac{(\frac{x}{2})^2}{sin^2 \frac{x}{2}} = \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \cdot (\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{sin \frac{x}{2}})^2 = \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \cdot (\frac{sin \frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}})^{-2} = \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \cdot 1^{-2} = 2
$$

Comment: The OP includes the tag 'limits-without-lhospital'

Comment: @LogLogLogLogx, hh, I hadn't realized it. Let me change my answer then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a Calc 1 appropriate answer.

We have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(1+\cos x)}{1-\cos^2x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\cdot(1+\cos x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}(1+\cos x)\\
&=1\cdot2\\
&=\boxed2
\end{align}
as desired.

Comment: Yep, this was the approach of my lecturer. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

With the power series for $ \cos$:

$$\frac{1- \cos x}{x^2}= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4!}+\frac{x^4}{6!}- +.... \to \frac{1}{2}$$

as $x \to 0.$ Hence

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2}{1 - \cos x}=2.$$